# Does Java's try-with-resources catch errors or just exceptions?

Tags: java, junit, exception

I have some junit tests which create some resources which should also be closed.

One way to implement this logic is using the `@Before` and `@After` approach.

What I did was to encapsulate the creation in some utility class to be reused. For example:

```
class UserCreatorTestUtil implements AutoClosable {
  User create() {...}
  void close() {...}
}
```

The whole point is for the object to close itself, rather than needing to remember to close it in `@After`.

The usage should be:

```
@Test
void test() {
  try (UserCreatorTestUtil userCreatorTestUtil = new UserCreatorTestUtil()) {
    User user = userCreatorTestUtil.create();
    // Do some stuff regarding the user's phone
    Assert.assertEquals("123456789", user.getPhone());
  }
}
```

The problem is that junit's assert keyword throws an `Error` - not `Exception`.

**Will the try-with-resource "catch" the `Error` and invoke the close method?**

* Couldn't find the answer in the [try-with-resources documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: OT: Just for the records: *"I have some junit tests which create some resources"* so you don't have **UnitTests**, what you have are *Module Tests* using a *UnitTest -* **Framework**.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle - while picking nits: *some resource* may just as well refer to a mocked out version, that still must be closed for everything to make sense.

Comment: @MartinBa: In case of the TO the Tests are creating an closing resources. That's not what *I* call a UnitTest. Mocked recourses do not need to be closed (by the Test). The Test only needs to check that the production code called `close()` on them if needed...

Comment: Both Errors and Exceptions (uppercase E) are kinds of exceptions (lowercase e).

Comment: @immibis but we can call them Throwables to be case-insensitive and unambigious.

Comment: @Thilo But case-insensitive languages are literally Satan.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It does not `catch` anything. But it does `finally` close all resources.

`finally` blocks [are run even when an Error is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464098/does-a-finally-block-always-run).

Comment: So I guess the answer is yes. It closes all resources because it behaves like in a finally block, which is called on any `Throwable`?

Comment: No, it simply doesn't know about any exceptions/errors.

Comment: Yes, it does its cleanup in the same way a manual `finally` block would do.

Comment: Note that finally works well except for `System.exit()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905006/system-exit-results-unexecutable-finally-block

Comment: It behaves *almost* like a `finally` block, as, unlike a `finally` block, it will catch all subsequent `Throwable`s of the `close()` operations and add them as *suppressed* throwable to the primary throwable. A `finally` block can’t do that as it has no knowledage about the primary throwable, if there is one.

Comment: @Holger: Well, it is implemented as a `finally` block *in addition* to a `catch` block that does not really catch anything (just records the primary throwable and rethrows). All the "action" happens in the finally block. See @Nicolas answer for details.

Comment: @Thilo: well, a combination of a `catch` block and a `finally` block still is something different than a `finally` block. That’s why I said “*almost like a finally block*”. But anyway, the pseudo code of Nicolas’ answer is only a formal specification and, as already said there in a comment, it makes not much sense to implement it literally that way, as, on the byte code level, there are no `finally` blocks; they are always implemented as an ordinary code path *and* a `catch` block code path and implementing try-with-resource as these two code paths in the first place would simplify the code.

Answer (score 37):

The pseudo-code of a basic *try-with-resources* statement is (cf [`Java Language Specification §14.20.3.1`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1)):

```
final VariableModifiers_minus_final R Identifier = Expression;
Throwable #primaryExc = null;

try ResourceSpecification_tail
    Block
catch (Throwable #t) {
    #primaryExc = #t;
    throw #t;
} finally {
    if (Identifier != null) {
        if (#primaryExc != null) {
            try {
                Identifier.close();
            } catch (Throwable #suppressedExc) {
                #primaryExc.addSuppressed(#suppressedExc);
            }
        } else {
            Identifier.close();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it catches `Throwable` not `Exception` which includes `Error` but **only to get the primary exception** in order to add as suppressed exceptions any exceptions that occurred while closing the resources.

You can also notice that your resources are closed in the `finally` block which means that **they will be closed whatever happens** (except in case of a `System.exit` of course as it terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine) even in case an `Error` or any sub class of `Throwable` is thrown.

Comment: Unfortunately, `javac` adheres literally to this convoluted formal specification. Considering, that `finally` is eventually implemented via code duplication for the two cases, it makes no sense at all, to store the exception in a variable and test it against `null`, when it is already implied by the code path whether there is an exception or not…

Comment: @Holger: Whether there was an exception or not is _not_ implied by the code path. Remember that the `finally` block is executed whether there was an exception or not. What code duplication do you mean (I guess the two `Identifier.close()`) and why does it annoy you? What would you suggest try-with-resources should do instead?

Comment: @siegi: on the byte code level, there is no `finally` feature, hence, a `finally` block is compiled by copying the action to every code path that could leave the block, plus an exception handler, i.e. `try { foo(); } finally { bar(); }` gets compiled to `try { foo(); } catch(Throwable t) { bar(); throw t; } bar();`, duplicating the `bar()` invocation code. There, it is implied by the code path whether an exception occurred or not, i.e. the first `bar();` invocation is the one under exceptional condition, the second is the one without.

Comment: @siegi: The code produced by `javac` as a consequence of this is discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25615417/2711488). In my answer there, I referred to this behavior as “an artifact of how `javac` works internally”, without naming “implements this like a `finally` block” directly, simply because I didn’t know that formal specification at this point, but seeing it now, things become entirely clear (and the general statement still holds).

Comment: @Holger: Oh, I thought about code duplication at the Java language level (i.e. the snipped above) and not at the bytecode level. I guess it was a design decision to have no special case handling for try-with-resources in `javac` but to simply "desugar" it according to the language specification and then let the JIT compiler do its job.

Answer (score 13):

Try-with-resources don't catch anything in and of themselves.

However, you can attach a `catch` block to the end of the try-with-resources block, to catch whatever types of `Throwable` you like:

```
try (UserCreatorTestUtil userCreatorTestUtil = new UserCreatorTestUtil()) {
  // ... Whatever
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  // Handle e.
} catch (Exception | Throwable t) {
  // Handle t.
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The idea behind `try-with-resources` is to make sure that the resources should be closed.

The problem with conventional `try-catch-finally` statements is that let's suppose your `try` block throws an exception; now usually you'll handle that exception in `finally` block.

Now suppose an exception occurs in finally block as well. In such a case, the exception thrown by try catch is **lost** and the exception generated in `finally` block gets propagated.

```
try {
    // use something that's using resource
    // e.g., streams
} catch(IOException e) {
   // handle 
} finally {
    stream.close();
    //if any exception occurs in the above line, than that exception
    //will be propagated and the original exception that occurred
    //in try block is lost.
}
```

In `try-with-resources` the `close()` method of the resource will get automatically called, and if the `close()` throws any exception, the rest of the `finally` isn't reached, and the original exception is lost.

Contrast that with this:

```
try (InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream("C://test.txt")){
    // ... use stream
} catch(IOException e) {
   // handle exception
}
```

in the above code snippet, the `close()` method automatically gets called and if that `close()` method also generated any exception, than that exception will automatically get suppressed.

See also: [Java Language Specification 14.20.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3)

Answer (score 4):

Misconception on your end: try-with-resources does **not** do a *catch*.

It does a *final* **finally**, therefore the kind of "problem" doesn't matter.

See the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) for further information!

Comment: But it does do a catch, so that it can preserve the original exception, if any, and add subsequent exceptions as suppressed exceptions.